# characters are shown as '#' when exporting table data to Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to export table data to excel file using 'tableexport' npm module(ver 5.2.0),
but the problem is some characters will be shown as '#'.for example,the characters of 'BUGCHECK_CODE:20001' will be all shown as '#', even though they are shown normally in web page. I can't figure out what causes this problem.please help!

When I hover the mouse pointer over these '#'s in Excel file , the pop-up message says:"date and times are negative or too large will be shown as '#'".

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the dumb question, however, I had this error a while ago and it was due to the cells being too small to hold the data so it just displays as a whole bunch of hashtags. If you could, could you please resize the cells and see if it gets fixed.